# Require two clicks to submit a form - JQuery (like stackoverflow review question)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to replicate the review post feature you see here on stackoverflow, I am struggling with the requiring two clicks to submit portion of this though.  My searches have returned multiple problems with *validate* but nothing quite pertaining to what I am looking for.

I have a standard form:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="review" value="Review" />
</form>
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(".Anchor").offset().top}, 300);
    return false; // to cancel form action
  });
});
```

How can I make it so when the submit is pressed it goes to the anchor, then the next time it is pressed it submits the form?  I would like to change the value from review to submit also, but I'm sure I can figure that part out after receiving a reply to the initial question.

A live sample of what I have can be found [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/-GiR/pen/eYzwjyo)

Comment: Maybe keep a variable to keep a track of the events performed and perform the scroll and form submission based on the value of that variable. You can use this variable to change the name from review to submit. For example:
`let hasUserReviewedTheForm = false`
Then change the variable value on the first click to `true` and then change the name and submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using a variable within your function, you can toggle the variable from `true` to `false` upon click.  With this method you can manipulate anything you want the second action to be within an else statement.

An example of this based on the code you provided:

```
$(function(){
  let hasUserReviewedTheForm = false;
  $('form').submit(function(){
    if(!hasUserReviewedTheForm) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(".Anchor").offset().top}, 300);
        //change the form name and change the variable value
        hasUserReviewedTheForm = true;
        return false; // to cancel form action
    }
    else {
      //Submit the form
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Them brain fart moments when you're like duh how did I not think of it this way.  Was way overthinking it,  thank you for the simple solution.

Comment: Haha! I too have been there!